# Pandas Time Series Resampling: KeyError: "['year' 'month' 'day'] not in index"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, time-series

Please Help

I have tried unsuccessfully to **resample** the data. It generates the above error, when DatetimeIndex is applied *it truncates the timestamp, removing HH:MM:SS*. It still does not recognise data as a Datetime object. Thanks in advance.

Source file can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B33XND8VAD8cV24wMUY2NVZSbXc/view?usp=sharing)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df= pd.read_csv('20170713.csv')
df2= df.loc[:,['sen_id', 'pos_id', 'heat_val', 'sat_val', 'timestamp']] 
cols = df2.columns.tolist() 
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df2 = df2[cols]
#print(df2.head())

df3 = df2.set_index(['timestamp'])
df3.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3.index)
print(df3.head())

pd.to_datetime(df3[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df3.resample('1H').mean()
print(df3)
```

Comment: so you want the index to be a datetime of yyyy-mm-dd? Can you provide a sample of what you would like your final output to be?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Much love :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the incorrect use of `pd.to_datetime()`, where you supplied  three columns that do not exist in `df3` as `df3[['year','month','day']]`. When instead you want to just provide a [series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html). Then you want to provde the argument `format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'`, which corresponds to your dates strptime format

```
df= pd.read_csv('20170713.csv')
df2= df.loc[:,['sen_id', 'pos_id', 'heat_val', 'sat_val', 'timestamp']] 
cols = df2.columns.tolist() 
cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
df2 = df2[cols]
#print(df2.head())

df3 = df2.set_index(['timestamp'])
#df3.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df3.index)
#print(df3.head())

#pd.to_datetime(df3[['year', 'month', 'day']])
df3.index = pd.to_datetime(df3.index,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df3 = df3.resample('1H').mean()
print(df3)
```

As an example, for readability, your code can actually be condensed down too,

```
df = pd.read_csv('20170713.csv')

#Preserve desired columns and reorder as df2
df2 = df[['timestamp', 'sen_id', 'pos_id', 'heat_val', 'sat_val']]

#set timestamp as index and convert to datetime
df2.set_index(['timestamp'],drop=True,inplace=True)
df2.index = pd.to_datetime(df2.index,format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')

#resample
df3 = df2.resample('1H').mean()

print df3
```

Comment: I am so grateful, your condensed code was even faster. Keep up the good work. The use of pd.to_datetime was slightly confusing. Thank you so much! Much love!

Comment: No problem! Glad too help